# Неправильное расположение примитива в blender

Tags: blender

При создании нового примитива в blender, он появляется повёрнутым по нескольким осям. Помогает только сброс до завнастроек, но в следующем проекте проблема повторяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зайдите в User Preferences, вкладка Editing. У опции Align to выберите World:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем нажмите Save user settings.